# Invalid Partition Table when trying to boot from USB

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

I got a usb with "hiren's boot cd" flashed to it.
Partition scheme is MBR / BIOS (or UEFI-CSM).

When I boot I get the error message "Invalid Partition Table". I checked BIOS if there were any settings related to CSM, but couldn't find any. The computer is a 15ish year old machine running Windows 7.

Any ideas what I should try next?

Comment: UEFI is unsupported on a machine that age - Check that the boot CD isn't UEFI only.

Comment: Yea, that's why I chose "BIOS" instead of "UEFI only". I still get this error. Is the PC too old to boot from USB? Do I need to brun a CD?

Comment: A good USB test is to download the windows 10 usb tool from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 - create USB then see if it boots. This usb device boots from both uefi and standard methods

Comment: Also, if you have a cdrom in the computer, most pc's boot from cd's - make sure that you change the boot order in the bios or look for 'f10 boot device' type messages at bios startup

Comment: Burned a DVD instead. Guess the computer was too old to boot from USB. Case closed.

Comment: Could you mark my answer as correct? thx

Answer (score 1):

On older computers, sometimes the only bootable device is a cdrom/dvd drive. Write a DVD and try booting from that.